# Selenium-Java - Upload images : element not interactable

Tags: java, image, selenium, file-upload

Selenium WebDriver 3.141.59 and Java 8, Maven project using TestNG 6.8.8.

The element does not have a Choose File option. "Drag and Drop or Click" element which brings up a window to select a file.
`ElementNotInteractableException`: element not interactable

Using POM Locator:

```
@FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")
 WebElement deal_image_input;
```

Element definitely visible as the method is called after other fields on page are completed.

Code:

```
public void uploadImages() {
    if (deal_image_input.isEnabled()){

       deal_image_input.sendKeys("C:\\ilmlsAutomationAddIns\\image1.png");
       deal_image_input.sendKeys("C:\\ilmlsAutomationAddIns\\image2.png");
       deal_image_input.sendKeys("C:\\ilmlsAutomationAddIns\\image3.png");
    }
}
```

DOM Screen shot:

[image: DOM screenshot]

Comment: Just because an element is visible doesn't mean that it is interactable. A web element can be both visible and disabled. Often, you can't really distinguish between an enabled and a disabled component.

Comment: Also, there are times where the element is complex and the interactable part is not the obvious part. An extract of the DOM and a screen capture might be beneficial to us trying to help you.

Comment: Lastly, you might not be waiting long enough for the element to be interactable. What kind of "wait" are you using?

Comment: Edit your post with ALL relevant code. Read all of the above comment and also include how you are obtaining the `WebElement` and how are you "waiting" for the component to reach a certain state (i.e. _clickable_)

Comment: Also, expand the "dropzone" `div` completely and retake your screenshot. I have a feeling that the component you need to interact with is a sub-element of that `div`.

Comment: Have you tried to look for some `input type="file"` element in DOM? if you have some, just send keys to it.

Comment: no input. Here is the entire node in the Dom 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group row mt-4">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="bg-muted p-1 b-r-sm select-bg-color bg-sky">
                            <div id="dropzone" action="" class="dropzone dz-clickable">
                            <div class="dz-default dz-message">
<span><strong>Drop files here or click to upload. </strong></span></div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

Comment: @Kelly I've found this solution https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/22199. I've executed the provided script and it worked for me (for http://html5demos.com/file-api site), so it might work for you.